# Image of projective objects.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $A$ and $B$ be two abelian categories. Assume that there exist a functor $F$ between them which is exact, full and essencially surjective.

If $x$ is a projective object in $A$, then $F(x)$ is a projective object in $B$?

Comment: I think you might need some faithfulness hypotheses for this to be true: the main difficulty is in lifting epimorphisms in $B$ to epimorphisms in $A$.

Comment: But the property that $F$ is essentially surjective doesn't help to do this?

Comment: No, being essentially surjective is a condition on objects, not arrows. It's not obvious to me whether your combination of hypotheses implies that $F$ reflects epimorphisms.

Comment: Do you know some hypothesis which reflects epimorphisms?

Comment: Well, adding "faithful" to your hypotheses will do it, but then $F$ becomes an equivalence of categories! Another possibility is to strengthen your exactness hypothesis from "exact" to "faithfully exact".